# Using Rstudio 3.4.3, shiny has stopped working

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have Rstudio 3.4.3 downloaded, and my shiny app has stopped working and requests For a new version of shiny to be installed. However, when I try to download the new version and restart RStudio I still get the same message.
Help?

Comment: Have you installed the newest verison from github or from CRAN?

Comment: RStudio isn't up to version 3.4.3 yet, they are still in the 1.x range.  That looks like an R version.  What version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: 1.1.383.0 version

Comment: i also have shiny 1.0.5 installed from CRAN

Comment: when i try to run my shiny app, i still get the message, "running shiny applications requires installing an updated version of shiny" - but i have the updated version? really confused.

Comment: Are you using any packages installed from Github?  Shiny 1.0.5 is current on CRAN, but Github has modifications that other Github packages might rely on.  (Github packages typically don't have useful version numbers; Shiny is 1.0.5.9000 there.)

Comment: I may have some packages from Github but i am not aware which one. what do you suggest i do?

Answer (score 0):

I had some unused github packages along with CRAN packages in the same folder and they were not working together. Therefore, i had to delete the GITHUB packages for my shiny app to work again.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem.  It's easy to see if a particular package came from Github (use `packageDescription("pkgname")`, and look at the last few entries), but I don't know if there's a way to easily list all packages installed from there.